# Credentials are required to create a Client Twillo in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, twilio

Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException: Credentials are required to create a Client in E:\wamp64\www\sms\src\Twilio\Base\BaseClient.php on line 70

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrEFi.png)

i will try this error solve iam tried. direct sid and token paste in src file

how to fix this problem and i want solution this error.

This is my code

```
require(__DIR__.'./src/Twilio/autoload.php');

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = getenv('xxxxxx');
$token = getenv('xxxxx');
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Specify the phone numbers in [E.164 format](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-e164) (e.g., +16175551212)
// This parameter determines the destination phone number for your SMS message. Format this number with a '+' and a country code
$phoneNumber = "+91xxxx";

// This must be a Twilio phone number that you own, formatted with a '+' and country code
$twilioPurchasedNumber = "+xxxxxx";

// Send a text message
$message = $client->messages->create(
    $phoneNumber,
    [
        'from' => $twilioPurchasedNumber,
        'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
    ]
);
print("Message sent successfully with sid = " . $message->sid ."\n\n");

// Print the last 10 messages
$messageList = $client->messages->read([],10);
foreach ($messageList as $msg) {
    print("ID:: ". $msg->sid . " | " . "From:: " . $msg->from . " | " . "TO:: " . $msg->to . " | "  .  " Status:: " . $msg->status . " | " . " Body:: ". $msg->body ."\n");
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details such as the source code and explain what you already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you check my edited questions?

Comment: The code looks good now. It seems that the account sid and auth token cannot be loaded in line 5 and 6. Are you sure the environment variables are set? 
You should be able to test this when you try to `print()` the `$token` and `$client`

Comment: I set two variable of values but show this error. i con't provide my sid and token so i write "xxxx"

Comment: Do you mean you entered your credentials instead of `xxx`? This code should contain name name of the environment variables which store the secret tokens. If you want to use the tokens directly in the code, you don't need to call [`getenv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Comment: Great, I covered our conversation to an answer to that it's easier to find. Feel free to mark it complete with the green checkmark button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me the environment variables are not set properly.

This code should contain name name of the environment variables which store the secret tokens. If you want to use the tokens directly in the code, you don't need to call `getenv()` and just defined the strings directly.